# How can I list all connections to my host, including those to LXC guests?

Tags: lxc, userns

I tried both `netstat` and `lsof`, but it appears it's not possible to see the connections to my LXC guests.

Is there a way to achieve this ... for **all** guests at once?

---

Essentially what throws me off here is the fact that I can see the processes of the guests as long as I run as superuser. I can also see the `veth` interfaces that get dynamically created per guest. Why can I not see connections on processes that are otherwise visible?

Answer (score 15):

The kernel indicate the connections state on `/proc/net/tcp`, `/proc/net/udp` etc. but as the namespaces separate the network stack if an application is running inside a container (a different userspace) and is connected to the network the host `/proc/net/tcp` won't show its connection,

`conntrack` can be used to show the whole machine connection **but** this does not work for some interfaces like wireguard...

`ip -all netns exec command` can be used to run commands inside all the userspaces **but** this is limited to userspaces created with `ip` command.

On the perspective of an application running on a container its network stack state is still visible on the host on the location `/proc/$pid/net/tcp` so as a workaround awaiting to write a proper tool in c, i wrote a little bash script that loop on `/proc/$pid/net/tcp[udp]` and join all the states to be able to list the whole machine connection.

The script first join all `/proc/$pid/net/tcp` or `/proc/$pid/net/udp` sort them, remove duplicate, translate the value to a readable text and print them (the script require `find`, `grep`, `xargs`, `awk`, `strtonum`, `sort` and `uniq`)

For TCP

```
find /proc/ 2>/dev/null | grep tcp | grep -v task | grep -v sys/net | xargs grep -v rem_address 2>/dev/null | awk '{x=strtonum("0x"substr($3,index($3,":")-2,2)); y=strtonum("0x"substr($4,index($4,":")-2,2)); for (i=5; i>0; i-=2) x = x"."strtonum("0x"substr($3,i,2)); for (i=5; i>0; i-=2) y = y"."strtonum("0x"substr($4,i,2))}{printf ("%s\t:%s\t ----> \t %s\t:%s\t%s\n",x,strtonum("0x"substr($3,index($3,":")+1,4)),y,strtonum("0x"substr($4,index($4,":")+1,4)),$1)}' | sort | uniq --check-chars=25
```

For UDP

```
find /proc/ 2>/dev/null | grep udp | grep -v task | grep -v sys/net | xargs grep -v rem_address 2>/dev/null | awk '{x=strtonum("0x"substr($3,index($3,":")-2,2)); y=strtonum("0x"substr($4,index($4,":")-2,2)); for (i=5; i>0; i-=2) x = x"."strtonum("0x"substr($3,i,2)); for (i=5; i>0; i-=2) y = y"."strtonum("0x"substr($4,i,2))}{printf ("%s\t:%s\t ----> \t %s\t:%s\t%s\n",x,strtonum("0x"substr($3,index($3,":")+1,4)),y,strtonum("0x"substr($4,index($4,":")+1,4)),$1)}' | sort | uniq --check-chars=25
```

The output look like: (note that the pid is not accurate and is just used to identify the container)

```
127.0.0.1      :80       ---->   0.0.0.0        :0      /proc/10176/net/tcp:
192.168.0.2    :33882    ---->   192.30.253.125 :443    /proc/10176/net/tcp
192.168.0.2    :34020    ---->   192.30.253.125 :443    /proc/10176/net/tcp:
192.168.0.2    :34162    ---->   192.30.253.125 :443    /proc/10176/net/tcp:
192.168.0.2    :36242    ---->   192.30.253.124 :443    /proc/10176/net/tcp:
192.168.0.2    :37324    ---->   192.30.253.124 :443    /proc/10176/net/tcp:
192.168.0.2    :40122    ---->   216.239.38.21  :80     /proc/10176/net/tcp:
192.168.0.2    :40124    ---->   216.239.38.21  :80     /proc/10176/net/tcp:
```

Also i found a great tool for managing namespace with some very useful commands that is [nsutils](https://github.com/rd235/nsutils)

Comment: Very helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think https://stackoverflow.com/a/40352004/1951468 should answer you.

So basically, the only way is a loop around your containers and `nsenter`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use `sudo conntrack -L`

> conntrack is a userspace command line program targeted at system
>    administrators. It enables them to view and manage the in-kernel
>    connection tracking state table.

If not installed, the required package is `conntrack-tools` (on Fedora etc.) or `conntrack` (on Debian, Ubuntu etc.).

Comment: Conntrack could also be queried by parsing `/proc/net/ip_conntrack`, which is effectively what your suggested program does. But both `lsof` and `netstat` use kernel information, for that matter, so what's the difference?

Comment: If run from host `conntrack` shows connections established inside containers. Both `netstat` and `lsof` does not show that info.

Comment: This does not work for me, it show the connections but not the namespaces connections...

Comment: @intika this is very strange, are you 100% sure there is active connection inside container? Can you leave `ping` running inside and verify again? Also in Ubuntu there is `conntrack` package not `conntrack-tools`.

Comment: Yes, `ip -all netns exec ss` show those connections, and `lsmod | grep conntrack` show `nf_conntrack, xt_conntrack, nf_conntrack_ipv4 & nf_conntrack_* etc` also i dont have `/proc/net/ip_conntrack`; `conntrack -L` does show the host connections but not those established inside other namespaces, and finally running `conntrack -L` from within other namespaces return an empty list @suside

Comment: @suside i guess this is happening because of the network interface i am using inside the namespace which is wireguard

Answer (score 1):

A similar workaround is to execute the netstat/lsof command on all network namespace with

```
sudo ip -all netns exec ss -p -ut
```

or

```
sudo ip -all netns exec lsof -i
```

or

```
sudo ip -all netns exec netstat -ltup
```

Answer (score -2):

So far I had luck getting the container connections by running netstat from the container:

```
sudo docker exec -it <containerIdOrName> netstat
```

Obviously, the container needs to have it installed.